# Mongoimport results in "no collection specified" despite having collection defined

Tags: mongodb

```
mongoimport --uri mongodb://USER:SECRET@appname-shard-00-00-tlxyp.mongodb.net:27017,appname-shard-00-01-tlxyp.mongodb.net:27017,appname-shard-00-02-tlxyp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=appname-shard-0&authSource=admin --collection scoringSystem --file /home/myUser/IdeaProjects/app/scoring-system.json
```

Arguments:

- URI: `mongodb://USER:SECRET@appname-shard-00-00-tlxyp.mongodb.net:27017,appname-shard-00-01-tlxyp.mongodb.net:27017,appname-shard-00-02-tlxyp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=appname-shard-0&authSource=admin`
- Collection: `scoringSystem`
- File: `/home/myUser/IdeaProjects/app/scoring-system.json`

This results in:

```
[1] 23452
[2] 23453
2017-10-17T20:00:28.633+0200    no collection specified
2017-10-17T20:00:28.633+0200    using filename '' as collection
2017-10-17T20:00:28.633+0200    error validating settings: invalid collection name: collection name cannot be an empty string
2017-10-17T20:00:28.633+0200    try 'mongoimport --help' for more information
 --collection: command not found
[1]-  Exit 1                  mongoimport --uri mongodb://(...output omitted...)?ssl=true
[2]+  Done                    replicaSet=Wamsteady-shard-0
```

I do not understand how mongoimport doesn't find the command "--collection" since it's a valid parameter as [documented here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-collection).

What is wrong?

```
mongoimport --version

mongoimport version: r3.4.9
git version: 876ebee8c7dd0e2d992f36a848ff4dc50ee6603e
Go version: go1.7
   os: linux
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must quote the `uri` parameter. It contains a `&` which is being interpreted by whatever you are running `mongoimport` in.

So, replace this ...

```
mongoimport --uri mongodb://USER:SECRET@appname-shard-00-00-tlxyp.mongodb.net:27017,appname-shard-00-01-tlxyp.mongodb.net:27017,appname-shard-00-02-tlxyp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=appname-shard-0&authSource=admin --collection scoringSystem --file /home/myUser/IdeaProjects/app/scoring-system.json
```

... with this:

```
mongoimport --uri "mongodb://USER:SECRET@appname-shard-00-00-tlxyp.mongodb.net:27017,appname-shard-00-01-tlxyp.mongodb.net:27017,appname-shard-00-02-tlxyp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=appname-shard-0&authSource=admin" --collection scoringSystem --file /home/myUser/IdeaProjects/app/scoring-system.json
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the connection string:

```
mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://testUser1:BtNuk3jO9myBOupf@rest.qks7o.mongodb.net/mainDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority" --collection dummyusers --file ./dummyusers.json --jsonArray
```

explanation:

- mongoimport = must have
- --uri =  must have before connection string
- "mongodb+srv.." = the connection string you use for connection to remote mongodb
- --collection dummyusers = is the name of the collection where you want your data to go, and you need --collection flag before it for it to work
- --file ./dummyusers.json =  is the file that you want to upload, MUST BE JSON, and make sure that you are in correct folder and path is correct
- --jsonArray = must have this flag, otherwise you will get "MongoDB Atlas mongoimport issues cannot decode array into a D" error

I made a whole video on my channel with link to code on how to setup the MongoDB localy, export data and import data into MongoDB remote, here is the video: https://youtu.be/I78wzFCXoqI